# How to get which item is selected in JMenu?

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I'm writing a `JFrame` with `JMenuBar`, but don't know how to get the item which the user has selected. Can anyone help me?
I wrote some simple codes like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test MenuBar");
    frame.setSize(400, 500);
    frame.setLocation(575, 225);
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu jmenu = new JMenu("Menu 1");
    jmenu.add("a");
    jmenu.add("b");
    jmenu.add("c");
    jmenu.add("d");
    menuBar.add(jmenu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read a [tutorial how to use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). Also use `JMenuItem` with `ActionListener` instead of `jmenu.add("a");`

Comment: Define _get the item_ . Mention what you want to do with this _item_ later on. Post an [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then you could get some help.